# Create browser-type app from iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, browser

Many iOS apps, are nothing more than "web-browsers", that connect to a mobile version of the website containing their web-app.

It seems like there would be some built-in library that is part of the iOS SDK, that can be used to act as a browser, with the ability to access only that site.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get started ? I'm not even sure what search terms to use.

EDIT: Is there also a cross-platform alternative for creating a browser than using iOS SDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question you're looking for `UIWebView` - it's quite simple to modify/subclass this to suit your needs, and while it may not be the most performant means of executing an HTML5 application, it can be done. Get started by [reading the Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html).

To answer the second part, there are several cross-platform alternatives to using the iOS SDK. Notable ones are [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/).